# Installing Puma on Windows error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, puma

Tried installing Puma on Windows and getting this error -

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions with: '--with-opt-dir=c:\openssl'
This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing puma:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-opt-dir=c:\openssl
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... no
checking for BIO_read() in -llibeay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details. You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/bin/ruby
    --with-puma_http11-dir
    --without-puma_http11-dir
    --with-puma_http11-include
    --without-puma_http11-include=${puma_http11-dir}/include
    --with-puma_http11-lib
    --without-puma_http11-lib=${puma_http11-dir}/lib
    --with-cryptolib
    --without-cryptolib
    --with-libeay32lib
    --without-libeay32lib

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1
.0/gems/puma-2.11.2 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86
-mingw32/2.1.0/puma-2.11.2/gem_make.out
```

Tried several solutions to try and fix the problem, but they all somehow end up with this error.

I have Openssl installed on my computer and have used it to do some SSL certificate stuff, so I'm definitely sure it's installed properly.

Anyone able to help?

Comment: I have it downloaded and I've opened it and used it to generate keys for SSL.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me (with x86 version), following these steps:
1.To install OpenSSL, I went here: https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/openssl-windows.html.
2. Running windows cmd as administrator, I created the directory C:/OpenSSL-Win32.
3. Following the instructions from step 1, I went to https://www.openssl.org/source/ and downloaded the opensslpackage for x86 (openssl-1.0.1p-tar-gz) and extracted it via 7-Zip to C:/OpenSSL-Win32
4. Still as admin, ran C:>gem install puma --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir=C:/OpenSSL-Win32.
Note: I was following the Hartl tutorial, and had specified gem 'puma', '2.11.1'. However, this method resulted in '2.14.0' being installed.

@Rajarshi Das, thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if I would have problem with sync my project to other Linux and Mac pc. I have changed them file to use '214.0' though...