# error while gem install puma in windows

Tags: ruby, windows, rubygems

while installing gem install puma I get the error below

> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
>       Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
>       ERROR:  Error installing puma:
>               ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    C:/Ruby21x64/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... no
checking for BIO_read() in -llibeay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Puma on Windows error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204784/installing-puma-on-windows-error)

Comment: Dear Soner Gonul, pls help me as where I can locate edit delete flag.

Comment: Hi Soner Gonul.. Thanks .. pls advise me as how i can locate edit delete flag.

Comment: Error message when installing gem install puma is...PS C:\Usersvasan\mystuff\SampleApp> gem install puma
    C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... no
checking for BIO_read() in -llibeay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir

extconf failed, exit code 1

Comment: Including parts of your question in the comments makes no difference. I've retagged your question so it will show up on related technologies and it's clear that this behavior is seen in WIndows (which **is** important). That should hopefully bring some attention to your question. Regardless, check out the link I've posted in the first comment as it's essentially the same question.

Comment: Thanks. have same problem when installing puma in windows x32 also.ERROR:  Error installing puma:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extens

    C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for BIO_read() in -lcrypto... no
checking for BIO_read() in -llibeay32... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***.............Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/puma-2.13.4 for ins
Results logged to C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86-mingw32/2.1.0/puma-2.13.4/