# Running Rails App using Puma over ssl in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, ssl, puma

I am trying to run my rails application using Puma over ssl in Windows ServerR2. I followed an answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30204784/installing-puma-on-windows-error). I have installed puma with the SSL directory and I run puma using

```
>puma -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?cert=C:\Sites\server.crt&&key=C:Sites\server.key' -e development -S puma -C config\puma.rb
```

Also, I have created the cert and key, using [this link](https://gist.github.com/tadast/9932075). But I get the error

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/puma-2.15.3/lib/puma/binder.rb:131:in `check': SSL not available in this build (StandardError)
```

Comment: Please refer to [this issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/971). You may need to install OpenSSL on Windows.

Comment: so you are trying to deploy your code on windows machine ???

Answer (score 0):

works great in rails 5.2.3 and puma 3.12

```
gem uninst puma
ridk exec pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-openssl
gem inst puma
```